# What is this kind of layout called?

Tags: html, css, layout

I was hoping someone could tell what this kind of layoutting is called ?
[See link](http://www.sebastiansejer.com/en/)

I mean, the way that the boxes are arranging itself beautifully, and no excess space. I've even seen websites where they rearrange if one of the boxes is enlarged or something.

So, how is this done ? Is it just pure CSS, via floats or something, or is javascript etc. involved ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a typical METRO STYLE,in this  each element is called TILES , started by microsoft in Windows 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called `Cascading grid layout` , using `CSS` and `JavaScript`, see more at http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is called [**MASONRY**](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

> Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing
>   elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort
>   of like a mason fitting stones in a wall. You’ve probably seen it in
>   use all over the Internet.

**[SOURCE](http://masonry.desandro.com/)**

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

pinterest layout?

If you only want to use CSS here is a [tutorial using CSS3](http://thecodegenie.com/tutorials/pinterest-like-layout-with-css/) only which is pretty impressive.

Start off with an unordered list:

```
<div id="container">
  <ul id="myContent"> 
      <li><img src="image1" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="image2" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="image3" alt=""></li>
     <li><img src="image4" alt=""></li>
     . . .
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then apply CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1199px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 1199px){
    #myContent {
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        -moz-column-gap: 0px;
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
        column-count: 5;
        column-gap: 0px;
        width: 1000px;
    }

    #container {
        width: 1000px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 999px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 999px){
    #myContent {
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        -moz-column-gap: 0px;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
        column-count: 4;
        column-gap: 0px;
        width: 800px;
    }

    #container {
        width: 800px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 799px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 799px){
    #myContent {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-gap: 0px;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
        column-count: 34;
        column-gap: 0px;
        width: 600px;
    }

    #container {
        width: 600px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 599px),
only screen and (max-device-width : 599px){
    #myContent {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-gap: 0px;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
        column-count: 2;
        column-gap: 0px;
        width: 400px;
    }

    #container {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/PJpAt/